# PDF data to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdf, csv

Does anyone know a simple way to extract a table of information from a pdf file and insert it into a mysql database without converting it to a csv or xml file first? I have well over 200 pages worth of content and converting each page will take me forever.

Comment: Inside a PDF there is no such thing as a table. Therefore there is no "simple" way to extract such. However if you first use [PDF2XML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2xml/) and then write a parser will make it superfluous to go through 200 pages manually.

Answer (score 4):

There is **No** quick way for that.

You need to extract content from pdf to text using some 3rd party application & then upload it to database. But yes, this can be achieved programmatically once the script is ready.

Example:
Download class.pdf2text.php from http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1

Then do extraction something like this:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$pdfobj = new PDF2Text();

$pdf_list = array('1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf');
foreach($pdf_list as $pdf_file){
  $pdfobj->setFilename($pdf_file); 
  $pdfobj->decodePDF();
  echo $pdfobj->output(); 

// using regex break the content in desired format & then store it to database

}
```

Hope this will help.